# Cannot cast JSONArray to another JSONArray extended class

Tags: java, android, json

I have a custom class in Java which extends to JSONArray like the one below

```
public class JsonArray extends JSONArray {
    
    public void myFunc(){}

}
```

Now I have a JSONObject that contains JSONArrays in it and I want to cast those JSONArrays to my custom JsonArray class so I can call `myFunc()` on it

```
JsonArray array = (JsonArray) jsonObj.getJSONArray(key);
array.myFunc();
```

But I keep getting an error in my log saying:

```
JSONArray cannot be cast to JsonArray
```

**Note:** I'm running this on Android Studio and this is not my actual code, it's just a replica, so in this case, we should assume all variables are initialized

Comment: It's like how you can cast a `String` to an `Object` but not an `Object` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you are trying to do won't work.

The object returned by `jsonObj.getJSONArray(key)` is clearly a `JSONArray` and not a `JsonArray`.  And no type cast is going to **change** the **actual** type of an object.  That is just not possible in Java.  A reference type to reference type cast in Java does not change the actual class of the object.

If you want to arrange that you can use the result of `jsonObj.getJSONArray(key)` as your custom `JsonArray` type, you are going to have to *create* it with that type in the first place.

How?

- Possibly using a JSON binding with a custom object mapper.  (But I have my doubts that approach will work.)
- Possibly by making your `JsonArray` a wrapper class for `JSONArray`.  And then do this to wrap the `JSONArray` instance that you get; e.g.

  ```
  JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonObj.getJSONArray(key));
  ```
- Possibly some other way.

The best way will depend on the actual JSON library you are using and how you are instantiating the JSON classes ... like `jsonObject` in your example.

But it is probably simpler if you don't *try* to subclass `JSONArray` like this.  IMO, it is only making things difficult.  Instead, just put the `myFunc` functionality into a domain class or a utility class or something.

---

**UPDATE** - If I was going to use the wrapper approach, I would do it like this:

```
public class JsonArray extends JSONArray {

    private JSONArray ja;
    

    public JsonArray(JSONArray ja) {
        this.ja = ja;
    }

    public void myFunc(){
        // whatever
    }

    // Wrapper implementations for all of the JSONArray methods
    @Override
    public java.lang.Object get(int index) {
        return ja.get(index);
    }

    // etcetera
}
```

You don't necessarily need to write all of that by hand.  Some IDEs can automatically generate a skeleton for a wrapper class from the class that you are trying to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to **@StephenC's**... I decided to use his second suggestion.

So adding a constructor to my **JsonArray** class that will take in an argument of a JSONArray, then I add all elements in the JSONArray to JsonArray

```
public JsonArray(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        String s = array.getString(i);
        this.put(i, s);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonObj.getJSONArray(key));
```

Comment: That's not how exactly what I meant. I will update by answer with an example.

Answer (score -2):

### What's Happening

Here you will create `JsonArray.java` class and extend it with `JSONArray`.
it mean your `JsonArray` is child of parent class `JSONArray`.

Now you have wrote code like.

```java
JsonArray array = (JsonArray) jsonObj.getJSONArray(key);
```

`JsonArray` is a child, and `jsonObj.getJSONArray(key);` is a parent. that was problem.

### Solution:-

Cast it by child class like.

```java
JsonArray array = (JsonArray) new JsonArray();
```

Comment: The cast in the solution is unnecessary.  And note that the solution doesn't do what the original code is (apparently) trying to do.  So I think this is an incorrect answer.

Comment: Just like @StephenC pointed out... Your answer doesn't provide a solution to my question and casting JsonArray to itself is redundant